# Quran: part of sentences(chunk of ayahs)

Tags: xetex

https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/macros/unicodetex/latex/quran/doc/quran-doc.pdf

in the above document in 2.11 it says that you can typeset chunks of ayahs. But I can't...

```
\documentclass{extreport}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{quran}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{bidi}
\geometry{ a4paper, left=10mm, right=10mm, top=20mm, bottom=10mm }
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{2.4pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\newlength \lead
\setlength \lead {16pt}
\setlength \topskip \lead
\setlength \parskip {0pt}

\newfontfamily{\turkishfont}{Garamond}

\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\LARGE
\setRTL
\setmainfont{Scheherazade}
\ToggleAyahNumber
\textarabic{
\quranayah[1][1-4]~\\
\quranayah[1][5]
\quranayah[1][6]
\quranayah[1][7]~\\
\quranayah[1][7][2-2] %as an example: this line doesn't working
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\setLTR
\switchcolumn 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\LARGE
\begin{turkishfont}
adına Allah'ın Rahman'ın Rahim'in\\
övgü; alemlerin rabbi olan ilahın\\
Rahman'ın Rahim'in\\
hesap günü onun yetkesinde\\

yalnız sana köleyiz\\
yalnız senden yardım isteriz\\
yönelt bizi doğru yola\\
ihsan ettiklerinin yoluna\\
azap ettiklerinin ve kaybolanların değil\\

\end{turkishfont}
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `Quran` package manual

> From ver 1.6 onward, the package is capable of typesetting not only a
> whole ayah but also any chunks of an ayah if the wordwise option has been
> loaded

So you need to load package with `wordwise` option like this `\usepackage[wordwise]{quran}`